# Implementing TN2154 In Interface-Builder

Tags: ios, uitableview, interface-builder, xib

I am trying add constraints to a `UITableView` so that on different screens the view resizes. I am hoping to get constraints that basically make the view always look like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JDU4T.jpg) (left, right and bottom margins 0 and top margin 100). When I set the constraints in my .xib I get a warning saying `Table View has ambiguous scrollable content width/height`. After a while I found [this](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/technotes/tn2154/_index.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS40013309) technical note by Apple detailing how to do what I want programmatically (I think it will work for `UITableView`s?). I was wondering if there is any way to do this in a .xib (seems like it should be a pretty common thing).

Comment: If this is in Xcode 6, that's a known bug.

Comment: @ScottBerrevoets Really. Just wasted 2 hours on google...hopefully others will see this.